# R: Identify per group the row number if value in a column lies between possible pair of values in two other columns

Tags: r

I have a question that might be simple but I just can't figure it out. An example of my dataframe looks like this:

```
> df.corrected
   Grp Grp.ind ini.1 fin.1 ini.2 fin.2 
1    A     A.1     0     5     0     5 
2    A     A.2     5    10     5    25 
3    A     A.3    10    15    NA    NA 
4    A     A.4    15    26    NA    NA 
5    A     A.5    26    28    NA    NA 
6    A     A.6    28    30    25    30 
7    B     B.1     0    15     0    10 
8    B     B.2    NA    NA    10    20 
9    B     B.3    15    20    20    25 
10   B     B.4    20    31    25    30 
11   B     B.5    31    50    30    50
```

I want to look in each group for the row number in which ini.1 for each observation lies between possible ini.2 and fin.2 values (i.e. ini.2<=ini.1< fin.2, for all pairs of ini.2,fin.2). I want to know the row number to create a new grp_ind id. My desire output should look like this:

```
> df.corrected
   Grp Grp.ind ini.1 fin.1 ini.2 fin.2 rownum New.Grp.ind
1    A     A.1     0     5     0     5      1         A.1
2    A     A.2     5    10     5    25      2         A.2
3    A     A.3    10    15    NA    NA      2         A.2
4    A     A.4    15    26    NA    NA      2         A.2
5    A     A.5    26    28    NA    NA      6         A.6
6    A     A.6    28    30    25    30      6         A.6
7    B     B.1     0    15     0    10      1         B.1
8    B     B.2    NA    NA    10    20     NA         B.2
9    B     B.3    15    20    20    25      2         B.2
10   B     B.4    20    31    25    30      3         B.3
11   B     B.5    31    50    30    50      5         B.5
```

So far I tried:

```
df.corrected<-df %>%
  group_by(Grp) %>%
  mutate(rownum=ifelse(!(ini.1 >=ini.2 & ini.1 < fin.2),
                   NA, row_number())) %>%
  mutate(rownum=ifelse(is.na(rownum),
                   row_number(which((ini.1 >=(ini.2%in%ini.2)) & (ini.1 < (fin.2%in%fin.2)))),rownum)) %>%
  mutate(New.Grp.ind = Grp.ind[rownum])
```

and also taking out which() in the second mutate() and I did not have any success. Because my dataframe has over 6k observations I want a flexible solution without using na.locf. I tried that solution before and does not perform well in the whole dataset.

Does anyone have a guidance on how to tackle this problem?

I thank you all in advance for your help.

Comment: What if there are multiple overlaps, do you want multiple rows?

Comment: Even if there are no overlaps, in this table in row 2 for example with the `<=` condition you've given both row 1 and row2 match

Comment: @Mike H. I did not consider overlaps as I haven't seen any on my data.

Comment: @Calum You. You are right. As I coded R, it did not show me those double matches. I will edit the question so it is ini.2<=ini.1<fin.2. And I tried it now with this condition and still does not work. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Javmi I have added an answer. Have a look and provide feedback if thats what you were looking for? Intentionally I have kept the `New.Grp.ind` as `NA` for row number '8`. If you really want then it can be changed to `B.2` as shown in your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach using `dplyr` is to self-join `df.corrected` by `Grp` and then apply `filter` to satisfy rules mentioned by OP. This will provide `New.Grp.ind` for matching conditions. Finally, for rows which could not meet matching rules we have join back (using `right_join`) with `df.corrected` by `Grp` and `Grp.ind`.

**Note:** I have assumed that `Grp + Grp.ind` represents a row uniquely in data. If not, then a `row number` should be added in data which can be using as part of `right_join`.

```
library(dplyr)

df.corrected %>% inner_join((df.corrected %>% group_by(Grp) %>%
        mutate(rownum= row_number())), by="Grp") %>%
  filter(ini.1.x >=ini.2.y & ini.1.x < fin.2.y) %>%
  select( Grp, Grp.ind = Grp.ind.x, ini.1 = ini.1.x, fin.1 = fin.1.x, ini.2 = ini.2.x, 
           fin.2 = fin.2.x, rownum, New.Grp.ind = Grp.ind.y) %>%
  right_join(df.corrected, by=c("Grp","Grp.ind")) %>%
  select( Grp, Grp.ind, ini.1 = ini.1.x, fin.1 = fin.1.x, ini.2 = ini.2.x, fin.2 = fin.2.x,
         rownum, New.Grp.ind) %>%
  mutate(New.Grp.ind = coalesce(New.Grp.ind, Grp.ind))

#    Grp Grp.ind ini.1 fin.1 ini.2 fin.2 rownum New.Grp.ind
# 1    A     A.1     0     5     0     5      1         A.1
# 2    A     A.2     5    10     5    25      2         A.2
# 3    A     A.3    10    15    NA    NA      2         A.2
# 4    A     A.4    15    26    NA    NA      2         A.2
# 5    A     A.5    26    28    NA    NA      6         A.6
# 6    A     A.6    28    30    25    30      6         A.6
# 7    B     B.1     0    15     0    10      1         B.1
# 8    B     B.2    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA         B.2
# 9    B     B.3    15    20    20    25      2         B.2
# 10   B     B.4    20    31    25    30      3         B.3
# 11   B     B.5    31    50    30    50      5         B.5
```

**Data:**

```
df.corrected <- read.table(text = 
"Grp Grp.ind ini.1 fin.1 ini.2 fin.2 
1    A     A.1     0     5     0     5 
2    A     A.2     5    10     5    25 
3    A     A.3    10    15    NA    NA 
4    A     A.4    15    26    NA    NA 
5    A     A.5    26    28    NA    NA 
6    A     A.6    28    30    25    30 
7    B     B.1     0    15     0    10 
8    B     B.2    NA    NA    10    20 
9    B     B.3    15    20    20    25 
10   B     B.4    20    31    25    30 
11   B     B.5    31    50    30    50",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: You are right assuming that each Gr + Grp_ind is unique